# VS2013 Update 4, can't open CSHTML files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, razor-2

I have a machine that can no longer edit CSHTML files in VS2013 Update 4.  The exact manifestation of this varies.  In some cases a modal will appear saying "The operation could not be completed."  In some cases the ActivityLog.xml file will be populated with errors:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Html.Editor.HtmlEditorDocument.FromTextView(ITextView textView) at Microsoft.Html.Editor.CodeBackgroundTextAdornment..ctor(IWpfTextView view, IClassificationFormatMapService classificationFormatMapService, IClassificationTypeRegistryService classificationTypeRegistry) at Microsoft.Html.Editor.Classification.RazorCodeBackgroundTextAdornmentFactory.TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__9() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Html.Editor.CodeBackgroundTextAdornment.OnLayoutChanged(Object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)

This does not appear to be related to the specific project/solution.  If I create a brand new blank MVC solution, targeting the 4.5.2 framework, opening any CSHTML in the new solution will demonstrate the issue.

If I create an MVC solution targeting 4.0 framework, however, the issue does not occur.  This appears to indicate that the issue is with MVC5 specifically.

What's particularly amazing about this issue is that I had corporate IT re-image the machine with a brand new HDD, I reinstalled VS2013, and I still see the issue.

Other machines in the same corporate environment (AD policy, etc) are working fine.

I have seen a number of suggestions for solutions around this issue:

Run VS2013 as Administrator:  No effect.

Reinstall VS2013:  Reinstalled the whole OS.

Run VS2013 in safemode:  No effect.

Repeatedly mash face into keyboard:  No useful effect.

Reset VS preferences:  No effect.

Answer (score 0):

Go to -
C:\Users\your user account\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

and delete all the file under ComponentModelCache folder.if there are any other folder under visual studio like 10.0 or 15.0 also delete contents of the ComponentModelCache folder. It works completely fine.